# Unzip large file from S3 and stream back to another bucket without downloading

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I have a lambda triggered when a zip file is uploaded. The zip file is large, 200GB+.

Using `@aws-sdk/client-s3`, how can I stream the zip file, extract and stream back to another S3 bucket without actually downloading the file to disk space?

Additionally, is it possible to get metadata information about the files as they're being extracted? I need the file name and size of each file being extracted from the zip.

Admittedly, I'm no AWS expert... perhaps there's a better way altogether to do this. I'm open to suggestions.

I found an example using the `aws-sdk@v2` library (see below), however it's not exactly what I'm looking for as it's only extracting one file to stream back and it's not using `aws-sdk@v3`.

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" });
const unzipper = require("unzipper");

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  //...initialize bucket, filename and target_filename here
  try {
    /**
     * Step 1: Get stream of the file to be extracted from the zip
     */
    const file_stream = s3
      .getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: filename })
      .createReadStream()
      .on("error", (e) => console.log(`Error extracting file: `, e))
      .pipe(
        unzipper.ParseOne("file_name_inside_zip.ext", {
          forceStream: true,
        })
      );

    /**
     * Step 2: upload extracted stream back to S3: this method supports a readable stream in the Body param as per
     *  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property
     */
    await s3
      .upload({ Bucket: bucket, Key: target_filename, Body: file_stream })
      .promise();

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error.message, error.stack);
  }

};
```

Comment: Unzipping 200GB+ data for a lambda function is way too much. I would recommend either changing the way files are uploaded or using an EC2 to unzip the files.

Comment: @jellycsc I was thinking that if I just stream from one bucket to another, piping the stream through `unzipper`, that I'd avoid "downloading" the zip to the lambda file system and handle large files. Are you saying that it's not possible?

Comment: I could also have the lambda spin up a fargate instance to unzip the large file. I could get the metadata of the zip file from S3 and use that to determine the memory need of the container.